# Как реализовать переход между метками при нажатии кнопки в Yandex map API?

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api, карты, яндекс-карты

Можно ли привязать кнопки к  **Yandex Map**, при нажатии на которые будет производится плавный переход между метками?

Каждая кнопка символизирует свой город.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:500px"></div>

<button class="city1" type="button" name="button">Город1</button>
<button class="city2" type="button" name="button">Город2</button>
<button class="city3" type="button" name="button">Город3</button>
```

JS:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

        destinations = {
            'Город1': [48.424020, 135.166384],
            'Город2': [62.067922, 129.703681],
            'Город3': [43.145268, 131.952203]
        },

        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: destinations['Город1'],
            zoom: 16.7
        });

    result.textContent = 'map init';

    function clickGoto() {

        var pos = this.textContent;
        result.textContent = pos;

        myMap.panTo(destinations[pos], {
            flying: 1
        });

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Можно программно управлять разными параметрами карты. [Вот пример с кнопками](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/mapparams?from=SO)

Comment: Только перейдите на версию 2.1 - 2.0 уже неактуальная и не развивается (там нет новых фич и не будет появляться поддержка современных браузеров)

Answer (score 0):

Переход на карте при нажатии на кнопку можно реализовать с помощью прямого геокодирования. Пример прямого геокодирования можно посмотреть [здесь](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode). Остается только доработать пример так, чтобы геокодирование срабатывало при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)